# Why dosn't facebook like this code?

Tags: php, html, facebook, iframe

I've made some progress on getting facebook to share some adds grom my website that are generated dynamically from mysql database. I can insert an Iframe on the main page of my site.

> ```
> <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php? href=http://www.webaddress.com.au/description.php%3Fid%3D'.$id.'&amp;width&amp;layout=standard&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=true&amp;share=true&amp;height=80&amp;appId=596610807121620" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
> ```

Then on the page this links to I have the following metatags.

> ```
> <meta property="og:title" content="Listed in the Two Year Olds section" />
>   <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" />
>   <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $row['horsename'];?> " />
> ```

Is there a more Facebook freindly way of doing this? As it seems to work sometimes but not all the time?

Thanks

Comment: which part is not working? the url content?

Comment: Your URL has a space character and you probably would have a better time with urlencode() usage

Comment: Wehn I debug in facebook it dosn't like the URL

Comment: @user2432677 and what does `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>` contain? maybe a sample string url? you have one?

Comment: What does the debugger say? What is the url to that page?

Comment: Object at URL 'http://www.justcuttin.com.au/description2yo.php' of type '' is invalid because the given value '/description2yo.php' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

Answer (score 0):

First off, what makes you think Facebook **doesn't** like this code?

Since you're saying it works sometimes and not others, I'm going to guess that the problem is that you're generating invalid HTML in some cases.  Any time you use text in the context of HTML, you need to escape it.  `htmlspecialchars()` can do this for you.

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['horsename']); ?> " />
```

I might also suggest using a template engine, as this gets a little busy if you have a lot of dynamic content on your pages.

Comment: @user2432677 A template engine like Smarty (or similar) will allow you to create HTML-like templates and then fill in all the variable data at once, handling all the escaping for you.  In addition, you can structure your site in a modular way, separating all of your main logic and code from the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help I added an og for the image  the meta propertys now look like this.

> ```
> <meta property="og:title" content="Listed in the Yearlings section" />
>   <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" />
>   <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $row['horsename'];?> " />
>   <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.justcuttin.com.au/photo/<?php echo $row['photo1'];?>"/>
> ```

I am now getting more reliable results.